Consul member in "left" state, but that server no longer exists
I updated a consul server cluster from 1.7.1 to 1.8.19 and everything went fine. The servers were removed and replaced and a new cluster was created with a leader etc. Metrics and everything look good.
However I was getting logs for agent.server.serf.wan: serf: attempting reconnect to ip-10-242-11-117.ec2.internal.dc1 10.242.11.117:8302. This server no longer exists (AWS EC2 server if it matters).
If I do consul members I get:
Node                           Address             Status  Type    Build   Protocol  DC   Segment
ip-10-242-10-225.ec2.internal  10.242.10.225:8301  alive   server  1.8.19  2         dc1  <all>
ip-10-242-11-117.ec2.internal  10.242.11.117:8301  left    server  1.7.1   2         dc1  <all>
ip-10-242-3-2.ec2.internal     10.242.3.2:8301     alive   server  1.8.19  2         dc1  <all>
ip-10-242-6-8.ec2.internal     10.242.6.8:8301     alive   server  1.8.19  2         dc1  <all>

You can see the old version member still a part of the cluster. I did force-leave which stopped the logs, but the entry in the member list is still present.
Is there a command that can clean this up? I have not found anything in help or online. It has been a few hours and I thought maybe it would be cleaned up but this does seem like some time to wait.
